# unable to use matrix variable in spring

Tags: java, spring

I am learning `springMVC` and encountered a problem that I am not able to use matrix variables as when I call `url` neither it is hitting `controller` nor showing any exception basically it is not triggering the code expected as I have the following classes:

**Controller class**

```
@Autowired
    ProductRepositiry productRepositiry;

@RequestMapping("/filter/{path}")
    public String getFiltered(@MatrixVariable(pathVar = "path") Map<String, List<String>> filterParms, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("items", productRepositiry.getFilteredProducts(filterParms));

        return "viewAll";
    }
```

**Repositiry Class**

```
private List<Item> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Item> getList() {

        Item first = new Item();
        first.setItemOne("firstOne");
        first.setItemTwo("firstTwo");
        first.setItemThree("firstThree");

        Item second = new Item();

        second.setItemOne("seconeOne");
        second.setItemTwo("firstTwo");
        second.setItemThree("secondThree");

        Item third = new Item();
        third.setItemOne("thirdOne");
        third.setItemTwo("thirdTwo");
        third.setItemThree("thirdThree");

        Item four = new Item();
        four.setItemOne("fourOne");
        four.setItemTwo("fourTwo");
        four.setItemThree("thirdThree");

        list.add(first);
        list.add(second);
        list.add(third);
        list.add(four);
        return list;
    }

    public Set<Item> getFilteredProducts(Map<String, List<String>> filterParms) {
        Set<String> keys = filterParms.keySet();
        Set<Item> itemOne = new HashSet<>();
        Set<Item> itemTwo = new HashSet<>();

        if (keys.contains("item")) {
            for (String one : filterParms.get("item")) {
                for (Item i : list) {
                    if (one.equalsIgnoreCase(i.getItemTwo()))
                        itemOne.add(i);
                }
            }
        } else
            throw new NullPointerException("value not found");
        if (keys.contains("one")) {
            for (String two : filterParms.get("one")) {
                for (Item i : list) {
                    if (two.equalsIgnoreCase(i.getItemThree())) {
                        itemTwo.add(i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        itemOne.addAll(itemTwo);
        for (Item i : itemOne) {
            System.out.println(i.getItemOne());
        }
        return itemOne;
    }
}
```

**URL**

`http://localhost:8080/Matrix_Variables/filter;item=firstTwo`

While hitting this `URL` `viewAll` (JSP page) is supposed to show data of `first` and `second` from `Repositiry` class but it is returning error

**Error**

```
HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.36
```

The thing I would like to mention that when I'm running this project with `("/")` it is working fine but when I introduced matrix variable it is not working.

and **dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/view/" />
    </bean>
```

All I want is to fetch values from repositiry using matrix variable to view but it is not happening,I am wrong there, but not able to find it,Can you help me with this problem.

Best Regards

Comment: why are you giving `;` in request URL ? try removing that

Comment: @deendayalGarg you can post it as answer and I'll accept it

Comment: added as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using ";" in request URL. Use "/" instead.

Comment: Did this work? All the matrix variable examples are shown with '';" . I have tried using "/" as well, but not working. I am having the same issue